# How to access enum in playframwork template

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.4

I have a model class with enum field

```
@Entity
public class Product implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public ProductType type;
}
```

I am pushing it to the template from an action

```
public Result index() {
        List<Product> products = getProducts();
        return ok(index.render(products));
    }
```

Now I am unable to access the enum field of Product in template. I tried this way but it is not compiling.

```
@for(product <- products){
                    <h1>@product.type</h1>
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `type` is a reserved word in Scala (like `public` and `class` in Java, for example). You can escape it using backticks:

```
@for(product <- products){
    <h1>@product.`type`</h1>
}
```